# Aurelia: if binding and content selectors

Tags: aurelia

I have found content selectors don't seem to work when an if binding is used on a parent element. For example:

**some-element.html**

```
<template>
  <div if.bind="true">
    This will appear
    <content></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <some-element>This will not appear</some-element>
</template>
```

This works fine if I don't use the `if` binding, but will not render `<content>` when I do use the `if` binding. Is there something I'm doing wrong here or is there a way to get this to work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be adding this to our documentation soon, but for now, here is @EisenbergEffect's explanation from https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/375

"No. That is a characteristic of the shadow dom. The content selection points have to be static. They cannot be added ore removed dynamically. If you want to hid them, then consider using show.bind instead."

Comment: Ah, thanks - I didn't think to search the Github issues! Will use `show.bind` instead.

Comment: Please also note that the `<content>` tag has been replaced by the `<slot>` tag in version 1 of Aurelia, in accordance with the latest changes to the Shadow DOM specification.  [Aurelia documenation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection)